# Pandas to sqlalchemy when you have many different CSVs with different column names

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to load in many CSVs from different clients that all contain the same types of data, but with different column names. For example

```
Source | Medium | Date
Src | Med | Conversion Date
Came From | Format | DateTime
```

All of these columns should be considered the same. So Source, Src, and Came From all need to go into a database column "Source." They could be named anything for different CSVs and be in any order, so some mapping needs to occur each time a different client is created.

Pandas has a to_sql function, but this requires you to manually input the column names and I don't want a ton of different tables, because I need to display the same table for each client later.

One solution I could implement is to have the interface require the administrator to manually select the columns and match them to the appropriate "master" column name. Then on the backend, just rename those columns before running to_sql.

Is there any other way that would be more efficient to perform this? Perhaps iterating through the dataframe and handling things row by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to create a table for relations(alias -> target column) or `config file`. Here is just an example, but I think you can understand my approach:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class ClientAlias(Base):
    # table for dynamic aliases
    __tablename__ = 'client_alias'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    alias = Column(String)
    target = Column(String)


class FinalTable(Base):
    # result table with standardized columns  - for all clients
    __tablename__ = 'final_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer)
    source = Column(String)
    medium = Column(String)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def prepare_aliases():
    """
    insert default mapping:
    Src -> source, Came From -> source, Med -> medium, etc...
    """
    for target, aliases in (
        ('source', ('Source', 'Src', 'Came From'), ),
        ('medium', ('Medium', 'Med', 'Format'), ),
    ):
        for alias in aliases:
            session.add(ClientAlias(target=target, alias=alias))

    session.commit()

# insert a few records with client column aliases
prepare_aliases()

# example processing
dfs = (
    # first client with specific columns
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'client_id': (1, 1, ),
        'Source': ('Source11', 'Source12'),
        'Medium': ('Medium11', 'Medium12'),
    }),
    # second client with specific columns
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'client_id': (2, 2, ),
        'Src': ('Source12', 'Source22'),
        'Med': ('Medium12', 'Medium22'),
    }),
    # one more client with specific columns
    pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'client_id': (3, 3, ),
        'Came From': ('Source13', 'Source23'),
        'Format': ('Medium13', 'Medium23'),
    }),
    # etc...
)

# create columns map {Src -> source, Came From -> source, ect...}
columns = {c.alias: c.target for c in session.query(ClientAlias).all()}
for df in dfs:
    df.rename(columns=columns, inplace=True)

# union and insert into final table
df = pd.concat(dfs, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
df.to_sql(
    con=engine,
    name=FinalTable.__tablename__,
    index=False,
    if_exists='append'
)
```

So you can add a new record into `client_alias`(or into `config file`) if you'll have a new client or there will be some changes. And all will works fine without code changes and deploying. Anyway this is just example - you can customize it as you wish.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I did since I didn't get an answer to the question for a while, but it's good to see that's how you would handle it as well. Thank you for responding.